# Qooxdoo tested json rpc javascript websocket client

Tags: javascript, json-rpc, qooxdoo

I'm starting a new project and I'm using [qooxdoo](http://www.qooxdoo.org/) js framework.
I'm running against a json rpc 2.0 server based on websocket communication.
I wonder if there's already a tested json rpc client for qooxdoo or should I pick any implementation like [jayson](https://github.com/tedeh/jayson).

Any considerations to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's always better to exclude the server communication to the lowest possible layer so you are not dependent on frameworks in case of changes.

We have our communication written in plain javascript.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Yes, you're right, I ended up writing my own ws json 2.0 rpc client in pure javascript.